# img size in master page changing img size in default page

Tags: css

There is an image in master page and an image in default page and they have different size but when the pages view in browser the size of default page became like image size in master page. I did the CSS code and it suppose to display the images according to their size, there is something strange here and I could not figure out what is it !

master page code:

```
 <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" style="height:106px"> <%--change header div size--%>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" style="background-color:black" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="img" runat="server" href="~/"><img src="pic/photoHeader.jpg" width="200" height="70" /></a>
            </div>
```

Default page code:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="container1" style="width:67%; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
        <img name="slide" src="home1.jpg" width="500" height="400" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6" style="width:30%; color: #FF0000; text-decoration: underline; text-align: left;">
        <strong>Business Units</strong></div>
</div>
```

CSS Code for master page:

```
img {
  border-style: none;
border-color: inherit;
border-width: 0;
height: 70px;
width: 200px;
```

}

CSS code for default page:

```
 .container1 {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
}

.container1 img {
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;
}
```

Comment: You should first remove style attribute if you are using css.

Comment: from where to remove attribute? yes i am using css which provided by bootstrap

Comment: In your html code you have a style attribute, remove it as will interfere with css.

Comment: html code does not have style!

Comment: Consider reading local html style attribute here, hope it helps. http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_styles.asp

Comment: You can try '!important' after your width and height declarations but I would really suggest taking a refresher on basic html and css, you've got some weird attributes on some elements and your CSS is redundant with your inline styling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The img css caused the error  due to img css changes any img in the project and in order to settle that the code of img in css must specify the container exactly.

Old code:

```
img {
border-style: none;
border-color: inherit;
border-width: 0;
height: 70px;
width: 200px;
```

New code :

```
.container1 .img {
border-style: none;   
border-color: inherit;
border-width: 0;
width: 540px;
height:400px;
```

}